# MySQL - Function keeps returning null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL function that will store the employee's time on projects and store it into `v_emptime` and then use that variable to calculate a total expense, like so:

```
delimiter //

create function F_COUNT_EDUCATION (p_empno char(6)) returns decimal(10, 2)
begin

    declare v_emptime decimal(5, 2);
    declare output decimal(10, 2);

    select sum(emptime) # There are multiple records for some, using sum() for total time
        into @v_emptime
        from empprojact
        where empno = p_empno;

    # if I return v_emptime here it will be null

    select (@v_emptime * comm + salary + bonus) expense 
        into @output
        from employee
        where empno = p_empno;

    return @output;

end //

delimiter ;
```

However, the problem is that `output` will always return null. I've checked the data countless times and the data all have values. Which means I'm probably overlooking something very simple. Any help or insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would have thought that as well, but upon `desc employee` it's saved using a char(6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
Change name of "@output" variable. And change query this :

```
select  @v_emptime = sum(emptime) 
from empprojact
where empno = p_empno;
```

And :

```
select @newVariableName = (@v_emptime * comm + salary + bonus) expense
from employee where empno = p_empno;
```

Comment: Because into is create a new table

Comment: Example usage : SELECT *
INTO newtable
FROM table1
WHERE 1=0;